# Two files with exact same permissions, but one is opening read-only

Tags: virtualbox, read-only, emacs

On an Ubuntu 22.04 VM, when I look at my files, I see that they have read/write/execute permissions set up correctly for `root` and `vboxsf`:

```
$ ls -lrt foo.pvs bar.pvs
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 23492 Jan 24 12:08 foo.pvs
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  1328 Apr  4 09:50 bar.pvs
```

The user (me) is set up as a member of the group `vboxsf`. However, when I load the two files up in `emacs`, they act differently. The first file (which I'm calling `foo.pvs` here, but that's not its real name) works just fine, but the second file (which I'm calling `bar.pvs`) opens up as read-only for some reason. Is there some hidden setting somewhere else in Ubuntu (or VirtualBox) that is affecting this? If it matters, this is on a mounted folder with a Windows 11 host.

Additional fact I figured out while writing this question: when I open `bar.pvs` up using `vi`, it's ***not read-only***. Making a change and saving it out, however, doesn't change the status in `emacs`. I need to open the file in `emacs`, because I'm really opening the file up in `pvs` (SRI's Prototype Verification System), which is a skin around `emacs`.

Comment: Please add the OS and version number to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: delete the hidden file `.#bar.pvs`

As I was trying to add more detail to my question, I gathered the information I needed to figure it out.

When doing an `ls -lart`, I found a hidden file called `.#bar.pvs` file, but there was no `.#foo.pvs`. When I tried to delete this file, I couldn't do it from within Ubuntu (at least not easily, not even using `sudo`), so I deleted it from within Windows. From what I can tell, it seems the `.#bar.pvs` file was created when I was editing the file in PVS, but the system crashed while it was open and so it wasn't properly removed upon exit.

After doing so, opening it up in `emacs` no longer set the file to read-only.

Comment: `$ sudo rm '.#bar.pvs'`

Comment: @Hannu This needs some context.

Comment: I believe what Hannu is suggesting is that I could've used `sudo` to `rm` the files. Alas, due to the underlying Windows file system managing things, that was not the case.

Comment: Yes that was a quickie to indicate exactly that, if the VM cannot handle it's own files, then that is a bug.